# same slider in one line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider, I want to take the same another one in one line. I attach a picture want I want to do exactly. no issue with my slider its working perfectly.

This is what I want to do.

[image: This is what I want to do]

```
    <script>    
    function changeImage(event, a) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;
  if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("mainImage")[a].src  = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
   }
  }

</script>
```

html

```
<img height="250" width="500" style="border:3px solid grey"  src="images/g4.jpg" class="mainImage"></img/>
<br />

<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event, 0)">
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g1.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g2.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g3.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g4.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g5.jpg" />
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />


 <img height="250" width="500" style="border:3px solid grey"  src="images/g4.jpg" class="mainImage"></img/>
<br />

<div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event, 1)">
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g1.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g2.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g3.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g4.jpg" />
  <image class="imgstyle" src="images/g5.jpg" />
</div>
```

css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.imgstyle {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

.imgstyle + .imgstyle {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

'Sliders' shouldn't be any different than any other HTML element. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/gbuk3qbe/

There are many ways to put things side by side, but here is one:

### markup

```
<section class="section-name">
  <div class="thing one">one</div>

  <div class="thing two">two</div>
</section>
```

### styles

```
.section-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.section-name .thing {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good case to use css grids. You want the block of images to be side by side. Add a parent div element and give each block its own separate div and use this css:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;

}
.child {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

You'll need to add a media query if you want it to be responsive, but you can see it here with stock images.
 https://jsfiddle.net/n38uu1t3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting dimensions in pixels hence the sliders will always fall below each other when the window dimensions are less. The solution you need must use relative dimensions based on percentage. Refer the below snippet where I have done this. I have use `float:left` to position side by side. I am adding a clearfix for the parent, so that the dimensions are preserved. Read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Note: when you are designing for movie and tablet screens its better if you have the slider one below another, so you use media queries and set the width of the slider to 100%

```js
function changeImage(event, a) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var targetElement = event.target || event.srcelement;
  if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("mainImage")[a].src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imgstyle {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.imgstyle+.imgstyle {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.slider {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE6 */

*:first-child+html .clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* IE7 */
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="slider">
    <img height="250" width="100%" style="border:3px solid grey" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" class="mainImage">
    <br />

    <div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event, 0)">
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">
    <img height="250" width="100%" style="border:3px solid grey" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" class="mainImage">
    <br>

    <div id="imgstyle" onclick="changeImage(event, 1)">
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" width="20%" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" width="20%" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" width="20%" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" width="20%" />
      <image class="imgstyle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x250" width="20%" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```